# Drawing an arrow above node to visualize rotation of a tree

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

i have a picture of a tree transformation which visualizes a rotation. I would like to emphasize an arrow above the node `(Qx)` or on the branches from `=>`. The code is as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
    \node{$\Rightarrow$}
    child {node {$Qx$}
        child {node{$\psi$}}
    }
    child {node {$\vartheta$} 
    };
    \end{scope}
    \draw[->] (2.5,-1) -- (3.5,-1);
    \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
    \node{$(\overline{Q}x)$}
    child {node {$\Rightarrow$}
        child {node {$\psi$}}
        child {node {$\vartheta$}}
    };
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like the result to have one of the red or blue arrows added to the picture
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[bend]}]
    \begin{scope}
    \node{$\Rightarrow$}
    child {node (Qx){$Qx$}
        child {node{$\psi$}}
    }
    child {node (theta) {$\vartheta$} 
    };
    \draw[red,->] ($(Qx)+(-1em,0)$) arc[start angle=180,end angle=70,radius=1em];
    \draw[blue,->] ($($(Qx)!0.5!(theta)$)+(150:1em)$) 
        arc[start angle=150,end angle=30,radius=1em];
    \end{scope}
    \draw[->] (2.5,-1) -- (3.5,-1);
    \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
    \node{$(\overline{Q}x)$}
    child {node {$\Rightarrow$}
        child {node {$\psi$}}
        child {node {$\vartheta$}}
    };
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]